# Should there be an "Edit and Leave Closed" option in the reopen review queue?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I fairly frequently find myself wanting to hit the "Edit and Leave Closed" button when working in the reopen review queue.  The edit that was made needs tarting up, or some unedited material needs editing, but the question needs to stay closed.  There's an "Edit and Reopen" button; I'd like an "Edit and Leave Closed" button too.  (I should point out that I generally work on questions already closed as a duplicate of another.  Such questions need not be bad questions, so deleting isn't usually appropriate.)

The workaround is to open the question in a new tab and edit it there, but it would be nice to have a more direct option available.

Comment: ...why wouldn't you just vote to delete it?

Comment: Why should I vote to delete it?  It could be a perfectly good question that just happens to be a duplicate of another question.  (I usually work with the 'duplicate' filter — so the question was closed as a duplicate of another.)

Comment: So the system assumes that the first edit to a duplicate is an attempt to make it not a duplicate? I guess that makes sense, I don't know why I assumed duplicates would be a special case.

Comment: Yeah, duplicates would be a different beast. Might wanna mention that. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180075/editing-a-closed-post-should-not-automatically-cast-a-reopen-vote-without-prior

Comment: @shog9: question already updated to mention duplicates.  That question on MSO is interesting — that could also be a problem, though it is somewhat separate from this.

Comment: I think that this option should **only** be available for duplicates. I also think that there should be an option to exclude an edit from sending the post to the reopen review queue.

Comment: If there's a good workaround (go to the question itself and edit it from there), this will not have to be yet another option in the review queue. There's no need to have buttons for each and every one of the myriad of different possibilities that can be done to a question. For example, you don't need a "Reopen this one and then close the original one as a duplicate of this one instead" button either. Things like that.

Comment: @MrLister if that were true, people would not be as confused on the H&I queue when they find a question that they feel it should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that there is a workaround, and that the 'Edit and Leave Closed' option really only makes sense for questions closed as a duplicate of another, there probably isn't enough of a use case to warrant the effort of adding the option.  The added friction isn't so severe as to be a major problem; there are other things on the SO/SE network of sites that more urgently need attention (e.g. Documentation, though I know it is getting at least some of the needed attention).

So, I withdraw the proposal.

I plan to leave the question undeleted so anybody can refer to it in the future.